# Probability of Overlap of Sample Subjects from Two Groups 4 SDs Apart

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, distribution-tails

This question came up a little while ago but unfortunately was put on hold. However, I found it intriguing as I had never come across a question like this before. There are $2$ groups of $30$ people randomly selected from $2$ normally distributed populations with identical standard deviations but their means for a particular characteristic are $4$ standard deviations apart. What is the probability of an overlap of the $2$ persons with the highest and lowest statistic from the lowest and highest groups respectively?

My Attempt: The area of overlap for the two distributions is $.0456$. This is twice the area of a single tail either greater or lower than $2$ SDs from the mean. Additionally, the probability of getting at least one person from a group in the overlap zone is $^{30}C_1\cdot.9544^{29}\cdot .0456 + ^{30}C_2\cdot .9544^{28}\cdot .0456^2.............^{30}C_7\cdot .9544^{23}\cdot .0456^7$. The series reduces to levels of insignificance beyond the $7$th term.

The probability has to consider the different number combinations of people in the overlap zone as well as the probability of overlap in the zone. Limiting this consideration to $1$ to $7$ people from each group, these combinations are $1,1; 1,2; 2,1; 2,2; 3,1; 1,3; 3,2; 2,3; 3,3........7,7$. For the probability of overlap with $1,1$ in the overlap zone, we have equal probability of order, AB or BA where BA is an overlap so this probability is $\frac{1}{2}$. For $1,2$ we have equal outcomes of A,B,B; B,A,B and B,B,A so the probability of overlap is $\frac{2}{3}$. Generally, this part of the probability calculation is $$\frac{(n_1+n_2)!-1}{n_1!\cdot n_2!}$$ So, the probability of overlap in the overlap zone containing $4$ from group A and $5$ from group B would be:

$$\frac{(4+5)!-1}{4!\cdot 5!}= \frac{125}{126}$$

Putting this all together I get:
$$P(A,B \ \text{overlap} \ge 1) = \frac{1}{2}(30\cdot .9544^{29}\cdot .0456)^2 + 2\cdot \frac{2}{3}(30\cdot .9544^{29}\cdot .0456)(^{30}C_2\cdot .9544^{28}\cdot .0456^2) + \frac{5}{6}(^{30}C_2\cdot .9544^{28}\cdot .0456^2)^2 + 2\cdot \frac{3}{4}(30\cdot .9544^{29}\cdot .0456)(^{30}C_3\cdot .9544^{27}\cdot .0456^3) + 2\cdot \frac{9}{10}(^{30}C_2\cdot .9544^{28}\cdot .0456^2)(^{30}C_3\cdot .9544^{27}\cdot .0456^3) + \frac{19}{20}(^{30}C_3\cdot .9544^{27}\cdot .0456^3)^2 + ............ \frac{3431}{3432}(^{30}C_7\cdot .9544^{23}\cdot .0456^7)^2 = .4044$$

Does anyone want to comment on the method or correctness or have a simpler method for doing this calculation?

I did look at a $(1 - p)$ type solution of not being in the overlap zone or only A's or only B's in the zone plus not overlapping when both A's and B's were in the zone but this turned out to be just as long as the method I used.

[image]

I think I can see the flaw in my reasoning. An overlap of members between group A and B isn't limited to the region of overlap of distribution curves. That is, an A member can be outside the overlap zone but still be further to the right than a B member in the overlap zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried a Monte Carlo simulation, with the result that the probability of an overlap is about $0.523$.

First, here is my version of the problem statement.  We have $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots , X_{30}$ and $Y_1, Y_2, X_3, \dots , Y_{30}$, where each $X_i$ is drawn independently from a Normal distribution with mean $-2$ and standard deviation $1$, and each $Y_i$ is drawn independently from a Normal distribution with mean $2$ and standard deviation $1$. The difference of the means is therefore $4$ standard deviations.  We would like to know the probability that the maximum of $X_1, X_2, X_3, \dots , X_{30}$ is greater than the minumum of $Y_1, Y_2, X_3, \dots , Y_{30}$.

One way to estimate the desired probability is to simulate many trials, using a pseudo-random number generator to generate the Normal variables.  When I ran $10^6$ trials, the result was that the max $X$ was greater than the min $Y$ in $523,460$ cases, so the estimated probability is about $0.523$. A $95\%$ confidence interval for the probability is $0.5225$ to $0.5244$.

I used R for the simulation. The purpose of the set.seed statement at the start is to make the results reproducible, so anyone running the same code should get exactly the same results.

```
> set.seed(1234)
> ntrials <- 1e6
> nsucc <- 0
> for (t in 1:ntrials) {
+   xmax <- max(rnorm(30, -2, 1))
+   ymin <- min(rnorm(30, 2, 1))
+   if (xmax > ymin)
+     nsucc <- nsucc + 1
+ }
> nsucc 
[1] 523460
> prop.test(nsucc, ntrials)

        1-sample proportions test with continuity correction

data:  nsucc out of ntrials, null probability 0.5
X-squared = 2201.4, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: true p is not equal to 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.5224805 0.5244393
sample estimates:
      p 
0.52346
```

Comment: Thanks for doing that. The probability of at least one person from both groups being in the overlap zone is $p = (1 - .9544^{30})^2 = .5677$. The probability of there being exactly one from each group in the overlap zone is $(30\cdot .9544^{29}\cdot .0456)^2 = .1249$. It is reasonable to think that the probability of overlap in this situation is 0.5. In which case .06245 for both overlapping and not overlapping. This reduces the probability of overlap to .5677 - .06245 = 50525. Either there is something wrong with my reasoning here or there is something different in the simulation. Thoughts?

Comment: @PhilH What is your definition of "the overlap zone"?  I think I may have misunderstood that part of the problem.  (That's why I gave my version of the problem statement, in case of misunderstanding.)

Comment: Side by side normal distributions this far apart have overlapping  tails by the area outside of 2 standard deviations which, for a single tail is .0228. As these tails overlap each of the other distributions, the total area of overlap is 2(.0228) = .0456$ If I were to simulate this using a RNG, I would use numbers 1 to 10000 whereby numbers 1 to 456 would be in the overlap zone and numbers 457 to 10 000 not. Each trial would select 2 sets of 30 numbers, with any number in the first set in the range 1 to 456 being higher than any number in the second set in the range 1 to 456 as an overlap.

Comment: @PhilH OK, I misunderstood the problem. So if I now understand correctly, you want to know the probability that the max X is more than 2 standard deviations above the mean and the min Y is more than 2 standard deviations below the mean?

Comment: @ awkward I revised my question by adding a sketch. I can now see the flaw in my reasoning, as the overlap of A and B group members isn't limited to the overlap region I indicate. Your simulation is probably correct but figuring out the math for a theoretical determination is getting too complex. It looks like integrals are involved. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case, let us assume without loss of generality that for some $\mu > 0$, $$X_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(-\mu, 1), \quad Y_i \sim \operatorname{Normal}(\mu,1),$$ and $X_i$ and $Y_i$ for each $i \in \{1, 2, \ldots, n\}$ are IID.  We want to calculate $$\Pr[X_{(n)} > Y_{(1)}],$$ where $X_{(n)} = \max_i X_i$ is the maximum order statistic of the sample from $X$, and $Y_{(1)} = \min_i Y_i$ is the minimum order statistic of the sample from $Y$.  It is not difficult to see that $$F_{X_{(n)}}(x) = \Pr[\max_i X_i \le x] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[X_i \le x] \overset{\text{id}}{=} F_X(x)^n,$$ thus $$f_{X_{(n)}}(x) = n f_X(x) F_X(x)^{n-1},$$ where $f_X$ and $F_X$ are the density and cumulative distribution functions of $X$, respectively.  Similarly, $$F_{Y_{(1)}}(y) = 1 - \Pr[\min_i Y_i > y] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} 1 - \prod_{i=1}^n \Pr[Y_i > y] \overset{\text{id}}{=} 1 - (1 - F_Y(y))^n,$$ and $$f_{Y_{(1)}}(y) = nf_Y(y)(1 - F_Y(y))^{n-1}.$$  Then $$\Pr[X_{(n)} > Y_{(1)}] = \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty \Pr[X_{(n)} > y]f_{Y_{(1)}}(y) \, dy = n \int_{y=-\infty}^\infty (1 - F_X(y)^n)f_Y(y) (1 - F_Y(y))^{n-1} \, dy.$$
Unfortunately this integral does not have a closed form for general $n$ and $\mu$, but it can be numerically integrated for the specific choice $n = 30$, $\mu = 2$, yielding $$0.52346740582758868816989507158239333395206638679228\ldots.$$

A plot of the probability of "overlap" for $n = 1, 2, \ldots, 100$ is provided below.

[image]

Note that the shape of the curve would be different for various choices of $\mu$; e.g., as $\mu$ increases, the curve will flatten out.  A plot of the probability as a function of both $n$ and $\mu \in [0,5]$ looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Interesting, I'll have to study it some but your answer is the same as the simulation which is encouraging. Further to this question, I posted a very simplified version of this question which turned out to be solvable with a double integral. See   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2836065/probability-of-finding-particle-a-to-the-left-of-particle-b  Maybe you could comment on a contrast of these two problems. Thanks for your solution here.

Comment: @PhilH The other question is a specific case of the integral described in the above answer, corresponding to the case where the distribution of the maximum and minimum order statistics are $$f_{X_{(n)}}(x) = 1/2 - x/8, \quad f_{Y_{(1)}}(y) = y/8,$$ and $n = 1$; except in the other question, you asked for the complementary probability of $a$ being to the left of $b$; i.e., $\Pr[X_{(n)} < Y_{(1)}]$--no "overlap" as it were.  But the principle is the same.