# Probability of Finding Particle a to the Left of Particle b

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Two particles are located somewhere between a left and right partition 4 inches apart as shown in the diagram below. The probability of each particle being located a distance x from the left partition is given by the following two equations:

$$P_a = 0.5 - \frac{x}{8}$$

$$P_b = \frac{x}{8}$$

[image]

What is the probability that particle a will be found to the left of particle b?

My attempt uses an approximation method much like finding the area under a graph by the trapezoid method. I divide the 4 inch region between the partitions into n equal widths and sum all the probabilities of particle a being in each region with particle b being to the right. The more divisions there are the more accurate the answer.

Example 1:

$n=4: P = \frac{(7\cdot 15)+(5\cdot 12)+(3\cdot 7)+(1\cdot 0)}{16^2} = .7266$

[image]

Eample 2:

For $n=8: P = \frac{(15\cdot 63)+(13\cdot 60)+(11\cdot 55)+(9\cdot 48)(7\cdot 39)+(5\cdot 28)+(3\cdot 15)+(1\cdot 0)}{64^2} = .7861$

As $n$ increases the accuracy increases and will be precise as $n\to \infty$

My question, is there a mathematically more elegant way of caculating this?

Comment: This is a simple problem, needing no "infinitesimal" partitions of any sort. But you should clearly define the underlying random model. The probability that particle a is at $x$ is $0$ (I guess), and similarly for the particle b. It is unclear whether your formulas try to convey the probability density $f_a(x)$ or the cumulative distribution function $F_a(x)$ of particle a, resp. b.

Comment: "The probability that particle a is at x is 0 (I guess)" I don't quite understand this comment. The probability that either particle is at a distance x from the left partition is given by the equations which can be zero at x = 4 for "a" and at x = 0 for "b".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think your $P_a, \ P_b$ are the probability density functions of the position of your particles, since each integrates to 1 over the interval $[0, 4]$. I'm also going to assume that positions of the particles are independent. To compute the probability simply evaluate the integral

$$ \int_0^4 \int_0^y \Big(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{8} \Big)\Big(\frac{y}{8}\Big) \ dx \ dy = 4 \Big(\frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{8}\Big) \approx 0.8333. $$

Comment: A double integral and the answer you get is as close to what I can figure with my primitive method. Thanks

Comment: I'm rusty on double integrals, I think the order is from inside to outside. FYI, this solution method is for slightly overlapping  normal distributions to figure the probability of a crossover of sample subjects. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, inside to outside -- you're integrating the function $f(y) = \frac{y}{8} \int_0^y \Big(\frac{1}{2} - \frac{x}{8} \Big) \ dx$ over $[0, 4]$.